# 2.4ghz wifi connects but doesn't work while 5ghz does work

Tags: networking, wireless-networking

I have made a lot of calls with my provider but they can't seem to find the problem the only thing they say is that it's normal that 2.4ghz has a further range but bad connection.

But I have 2 bars wifi on the 2.4ghz network and I can connect to it. When I go to a website on my phone I see it's loading (the blue bar goes till about 30%) but nothing happens after that.

I am struggling a long time with this problem what can I do against this?

My ping test results:

[image]

I also tried to run a test on the `speedtest` app. First it took about 5 minutes to prepare for the test it didn't start. After a while it came up with these results which look good to me. My max download speed is 300mb/ps but I don't expect to come anywhere near that on wifi on this distance.

[image]

Comment: Do you control your own Wi-Fi AP, or is this some kind of Wi-Fi ISP? Also, why not just use 5GHz?

Comment: The ISP is Ziggo in the Netherlands. The 5GHz works but my room is on top floor which the 5GHz can't reach.

Comment: Run a ping for a while, maybe 100 pings, to a server you care about, and see what your loss rate and average latency is.

Comment: I used the app "Free Ping" on my phone and pinged to 8.8.8.8. It sent 14 packages I ran the app a couple times. First time it received 14, then 13, then 16. Not sure what is going on..

Comment: I just noticed I can send messages on facebook while I can't search for anything in Safari on google

Comment: Your phone supports 2.4GHz and 5.0 GHz.  Depending on the age of the phone it might not.

Comment: It's an iPhone 6 I don't think that's the problem. Also there are times that it does work, currently it's working fine but on certain times it doesn't. I think it's mostly at night that it doesn't work.

Comment: Go stand next to the AP, and turn your Wi-Fi interface off and back on (or reboot your phone if that's easier). Does 2.4GHz successfully load pages now, while you're still right next to the AP? If so, then your problem is just that your top-floor room is on the very edge of the network. Never believe the signal bars, they're always a lie. Just because you have two bars doesn't mean you're not far enough out of range to have an unusable network.

Comment: Getting closer to the AP doesn't help. The same problem exists.